# In Javafx Setting System.in to read from TextField?

Tags: javafx

I am working in serial port communication,How to cascade `textField.getText()` in `System.in`I   referred this link  [Setting System.in to read from JTextField](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10951116/setting-system-in-to-read-from-jtextfield.Code)  [written](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10951116/setting-system-in-to-read-from-jtextfield) in `swing`..Please advise me to write this code in `javafx`
thanks.

Comment: `System.in` is used to read user input from `command line` and `Textfield` is used to read user input from `GUI`. Why do you want to combine them ?

Comment: @ItachiUchiha i am worked from serial communication project,developed gui with interact with hardware so in need, or any solution.